# Looking for an open source tool like GroupSpaces

Tags: webapp-rec, open-source, events

GroupSpaces has ability to manage multiple groups, mailing list, member management, wiki, file management and event management for groups.

Comment: Google Groups + Google Docs

Comment: This don't do member management

Comment: Bounty requester here: while there are plenty of collab or facebook-like webapps, I can't find any open-source app specifically for membership, like the one you'd want to run when ruling a club

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free open source tool like http://dotproject.net

Answer (score 0):

I really like so much of TeamBox, with some adapt you can get all this things. And the code is available on GitHub.

[Teambox source code](https://github.com/teambox/teambox)

Comment: Thanks, but it's more a collaboration tool than a membership (member coordinates, and list management) tool

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Analyzing  better those core functions, we have a local server running our Teambox fork, so we had to develop all those "integrations". I will try to commit this project at GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cyn.in](http://www.cynapse.com/cynin/features)

```
Collaborative Applications 
Spaces 
Social Applications 
Productivity and Interfaces 
Organization and Management 
Search, Navigation and Retrieval 
Customize and Extend 
Technology Platform
```

## [BigTent](http://www.bigtent.com/features)

I know it's not open source, but It seems to fit your requirements. Features listed, are -

```
Member Management
Shared Admin Access
Payment Processing
Subgroups
Group Communication
Calendar and Event RSVP
Photo and File Sharing
Reviews and Classifieds
Public Group Page
Private and Secure
```

[Few more options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collaborative_software#Open_source_software) are listed there at Wikipedia.

Comment: both are nice, especially cyn.in but no mailing list management...

Comment: You could mix cyn.in and phplist. And I'm pretty sure, there'd be a way to implement mailing list in cynin. They just didn't mention it like that.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/)

> ### BuddyPress
>
> Social networking in a box. Build a social network for your company, school, sports team or niche community all based on the power and flexibility of WordPress.
>
> BuddyPress is completely free and open source. Unlike hosted services, BuddyPress allows you to stay in control of your site and create a totally customized, unique experience

Answer (score -1):

I think [OpenCore](http://www.coactivate.org/projects/opencore/project-home) or [CrabGrass](http://crabgrass.riseuplabs.org/) should cover all your needs.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like [GroupServer](http://groupserver.org/) might do what I want, it is a mailing list manager with online administration of members and lists.